# how to Get value from url in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

**my URl:** example.com?v=1235

**i want:** to use String code on activity but when i am using code in activity it's giving me error

> error: cannot find symbol variable code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String webAdress = "http://vidhyapeethport.in/mob/index?me=1";
    WebView webView;
    private String code;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new okClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //enable javascript
        webView.loadUrl(webAdress);


        //Initialize And Assign Variable
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();  //mynavigationview is the name of your navigationcomponent

            MenuItem tit1 = menu.findItem(R.id.home); 
            tit1.setTitle(code);
}

    private class okClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.contains("1235")){
                  String code = "789";
                  view.loadUrl(url);
                }
                else{
                  String code = "456";
                  view.loadUrl(url);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String webAdress = "http://vidhyapeethport.in/mob/index?me=1";
    WebView webView;
    private String code;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new okClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //enable javascript
        webView.loadUrl(webAdress);

}

public void setTitle(){
//Initialize And Assign Variable
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();  //mynavigationview is the name of your navigationcomponent

MenuItem tit1 = menu.findItem(R.id.home); 
tit1.setTitle(code);
}

private class okClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if(url.contains("1235")){
code = "789";
setTitle();
view.loadUrl(url);
}
else{
code = "456";
setTitle();
view.loadUrl(url);
}
return true;
}


}

}
```

Comment: error: cannot find symbol variable code is solved @HasanBouTaam

Comment: but when i am using code it's blank means when running app it's blank no text in code @HasanBouTaam

Comment: I updated the whole code, check the update and see what happens.